# Best practices for handling network problems while package is executing

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

A project executes against multiple sites from a central location via VPN. Many of these sites are in rural areas of Mexico, where internet quality is somewhat less than desirable. This results in various failures in random areas of random packages in the project. Most of the time, network fails in the middle of data transfer tasks, because those are the longest running.

What is the best way to handle these conditions gracefully in SSIS?

Comment: There is no magic technique here. You have to retry the failing step or package.

Comment: Not looking for magic, looking for best practices. Edited topic.